# In Ruby, how to output json from hash and give it line breaks and tabs

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to format `{"key" => "value"}` to turn it into :

```
{
    "key" : "value"
}
```

for writing into a json file.
right now im doing :

```
hash = {"key" => "value"}
puts hash.to_json.gsub('{', '{\n\t')
```

to start. and this outputs

```
{\n\t"key":"value"}
```

Why cant i do the line break?

Comment: Fyi, the reason the `\n` didn't get expanded to a new line is that you're using single quotes. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Tried using double quotes, still gives me an actual "\n" instead of a line break

Comment: If you're testing that in IRB, that's because strings displayed as the "result" in IRB get converted using `String#inspect` before they are printed to the console. Try this: `puts '\n\n\n'` vs. `puts "\n\n\n"`.

Comment: no i'm testing this in a ruby file called through a bash script.

Comment: Okay, that's bizarre. So `ruby -e 'puts "\n\n\n"'` outputs `\n\n\n` for you?

Comment: my mistake @Ajedi32, i was sure i got the double quote thing right, just checked my file again i was using single quotes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yay for pretty things and yay for avoiding regexen!

Use the built-in [JSON.pretty_generate](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/json/JSON#pretty_generate-class_method) method

```
require 'json'
puts JSON.pretty_generate hash, options
```

Yay!

Here's the options:

- `indent`: a string used to indent levels (default: `''`),
- `space`: a string that is put after, a `:` or `,` delimiter (default: `''`),
- `space_before`: a string that is put before a `:` pair delimiter (default: `''`),
- `object_nl`: a string that is put at the end of a JSON object (default: `''`),
- `array_nl`: a string that is put at the end of a JSON array (default: `''`),
- `allow_nan`: `true` if `NaN`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity` should be generated, otherwise an exception is thrown if these values are encountered. This options defaults to `false`.
- `max_nesting`: The maximum depth of nesting allowed in the data structures from which JSON is to be generated. Disable depth checking with `:max_nesting => false`, it defaults to `100`.

Comment: Actually that doesn't give the line breaks like pretty_generate does

Comment: I think that `indent` is `'  '` (2 spaces) by default, not an empty string, or else, there would be no indentation when not specifying it.

Comment: And here it is: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1f1b62fb7bb0855788f3da7fdcf9e440ff617fb3/ext/json/lib/json/common.rb#L77

Answer (score 4):

As @naomik mentions, try using the builtin [`JSON.pretty_generate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate) with a tab for the "indent" option, for example:

```ruby
require 'json'
h = {:key => :value}
puts JSON.pretty_generate(h, :indent => "\t")
# {
#         "key": "value"
# }
```

The values for the "opts" argument to `pretty_generate` are documented at [`generate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-generate).

Comment: Interesting find; I posted a follow-up solution with your learnings (re: `JSON.generate`)

Answer (score 2):

For both line breaks and tabs, try

```
require 'json'
hash = {foo: 'bar'}
JSON.pretty_generate(hash, {indent: "\t", object_nl: "\n"})
```

NB! If you use single quotes with newlines ("\n") or tabs ("\t") they will not be interpreted as newlines but as an ordinary string containing one backslash and a letter. This is a common mistake. :)