# Preserve formatting when processing JSON

Tags: python, json, ruby, jupyter-notebook, whitespace

I'd like to load a JSON file, modify it, and save the results, without altering the original formatting. I.e. something like this:

```
 json_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('my.ipynb'))
 [...] # modify
 JSON.dump(json_hash, File.open('my.ipynb', 'wt'))
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495085/165753) `JSON.pretty_generate` is suggested, but  how do I retrieve `pretty_generate`s options (e.g. `object_nl`) when parsing the original JSON?

P.S. in case it's relevant the JSON file is a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: I doubt the `JSON` object computes the `pretty_generate` options for you when reading an arbitrary JSON file.Parsing JSON and making sense of format is challenging (it's not guaranteed to be consistent: lots of off-standard cases need to be considered). Why do you need the output format identically to match the input format in an arbitrary case?   You could write your own parser that keeps track of the source JSON and where everything is as you develop the structure, I suppose, then when you modify parts of it, write it back out using the original data and substitute changed components.

Comment: @lurker Thanks, I want to preserve the format, because otherwise the git commit has a huge diff which is very hard to read and review. Writing my own parse would be definitely interesting, but I'd rather not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I see, yeah, it would be nice to keep the same format. Once you generate your first version of the file with `pretty_generate` I would think subsequent updates to the file that are generated the same way would have sensible source differences from the prior version. Basically standardizing on the format generated by `pretty_print`.

Comment: Right, but some notebooks are generated externally and I have no control over their formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I originally wanted to use ruby since it has the useful `dig` method, but I ended up implementing `dig` in python, so I can use the `nbformat` package. I.e.

```
import nbformat

file = 'my.ipynb'
nb = nbformat.read(file, 4)
[...] #  modify
nbformat.write(nb, open(file, 'wt'))
```